# android studio emulator could not initialize DirectSoundCapture

Tags: android, kotlin, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

I just have a basic helloworld app in android studio 3.2 and I am trying to run some emulators to test the app with AVD manager, but the emulator just stucks in google logo  and eventually android studio times out and stops trying to attack the app on the emulator meanwhile I see following errors in the event log.

```
4:25 PM Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture

4:25 PM Emulator: dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID

4:25 PM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

4:25 PM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

4:25 PM Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

4:25 PM Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

4:25 PM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

4:25 PM Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

4:25 PM Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Same problem occurs with me.
The solution is :--

Change the ids.xml file. **Make  tag inner tag** , Like this

Before error, Code is like this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="workouttype" type="id" />
    <item name="txthello" type="id">txthello</item>
</resources>
```

Delete "txthello" and **make item tag inner tag**. You may not have "txthello" :
- After changing the code, look like this :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="workouttype" type="id" />
    <item name="txthello" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Now, that's it.!!! Run your app on emulator.