# android studio emulator sound

Tags: android-emulator

I am working with android studio everything was working perfectly but then I decided to try sqlite3 with android studio and in my first basic app i am getting emulator error like

> 16:50 Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture
>
> 16:50 Emulator: dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use,
>   or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID
>
> 16:50 Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without
>   DirectSoundCapture object
>
> 16:50 Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without
>   DirectSoundCapture object
>
> 16:50 Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
>
> 16:50 Emulator:
>   C:\Users..\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe:
>   warning: opening audio input failed

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the device?

Comment: I tried every single thing I have 4 devices so made changes to RAM and changed graphics from automatic to hardware then software. updated windows driver everything thanks for your time and help BTW.

Comment: Try this, it seems to be a similar error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51618206/android-studio-emulator-could-not-initialize-directsoundcapture

Comment: Friendly reminder there's no such thing as an "Android Studio emulator" - the emulator AS provides an interface to is a part of the SDK, **not** the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

so I got the solution for that

1. first of all close your android studio restart your PC and open studio it will ask you in the right hand corner for the updates if there is any available click on that. It will take a while, but can solve the problem.
2. If no. 1 is not useful for you try to check the windows update and then repeat step 1

Answer (score 0):

turn on microphone on windows 10 and install direct x
if you dont have input audio? intall virtual audio cable